# How to add json data and show in particular tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

```
import React from "react";
import "./Body.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Body = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState("2");

    const handleClick = () => {
      setValue("3")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/delivery_centers")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 id="myTD">To Be Dispatched</h1>
            <hr></hr>
            
            <button className="Dbtn" onClick= {handleClick}>LM</button>          
            <button className="Dbtn">FM</button>
            <button className="Dbtn">RT</button>
            <br></br><br></br>
            <div className="report">
                
                <span>    
                    <h2 id="r4">{value}</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r4">Shipments</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r1">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r1">WIP</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r2">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r2">Flash</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r3">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r3">Dispatch</label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="graph">
                <ul className="status">
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Forward
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        BFSI
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reattempt
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reverse
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        KYC
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        C2C
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="dsbtn">
                    <h1 id="cdBtn">CREATE DISPATCH</h1>
                    <span id="arrow" class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_forward_ios</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Body;
```

I want to show delivery center id in H2 tag above Shipments when I click on LM button with below json data

```
import React from "react";
import "./Body.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Body = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState("2");

    const handleClick = () => {
      setValue("3")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/delivery_centers")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 id="myTD">To Be Dispatched</h1>
            <hr></hr>
            
            <button className="Dbtn" onClick= {handleClick}>LM</button>          
            <button className="Dbtn">FM</button>
            <button className="Dbtn">RT</button>
            <br></br><br></br>
            <div className="report">
                
                <span>    
                    <h2 id="r4">{value}</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r4">Shipments</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r1">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r1">WIP</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r2">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r2">Flash</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r3">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r3">Dispatch</label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="graph">
                <ul className="status">
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Forward
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        BFSI
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reattempt
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reverse
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        KYC
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        C2C
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="dsbtn">
                    <h1 id="cdBtn">CREATE DISPATCH</h1>
                    <span id="arrow" class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_forward_ios</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Body;
```

I tried

```
import React from "react";
import "./Body.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Body = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

    const handleClick = (id) => {
        const Cname = value.delivery_centers.filter(val => val.id !== id);
        setValue(Cname);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/delivery_centers")
            .then((res) => {
                return res.json();
            }).then((data) => {
                setValue(data);
            })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1 id="myTD">To Be Dispatched</h1>
            <hr></hr>
            {value && value.delivery_centers && value.delivery_centers.map((val) =>
                <button className="Dbtn" key={val.id} onClick={() => handleClick(val.id)}>LM</button>
            )}            
            <button className="Dbtn">FM</button>
            <button className="Dbtn">RT</button>
            <br></br><br></br>
            <div className="report">
                <span className="rBtn">
                    {value && value.delivery_centers && value.delivery_centers.map((val) =>
                        <h2 id="r4" key={val.id}>{val.name}</h2>
                    )}

                    <label htmlFor="r4">Shipments</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r1">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r1">WIP</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r2">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r2">Flash</label>
                </span>
                <span className="rBtn">
                    <h2 id="r3">1</h2>
                    <label htmlFor="r3">Dispatch</label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="graph">
                <ul className="status">
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Forward
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        BFSI
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reattempt
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        Reverse
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        KYC
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                        C2C
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div className="dsbtn">
                    <h1 id="cdBtn">CREATE DISPATCH</h1>
                    <span id="arrow" class="material-symbols-outlined">arrow_forward_ios</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

export default Body;
```

I'm working on a React component that displays delivery center information and allows users to choose a center. I'm facing an issue where clicking the "LM" button isn't showing the corresponding delivery center ID above the "Shipments" label as intended.

Expected behavior:

When the "LM" button is clicked, the delivery center ID associated with "LM" should be displayed above the "Shipments" label.
Actual behavior:

Nothing happens, or the "LM" button disappears, or the ID is not displayed correctly.
Additional information:

Backend server provides JSON data containing delivery center details.
Any relevant error messages or debugging efforts.
What I'm asking for:

Help identifying the root cause of the issue and any specific code changes needed to achieve the desired behavior.
Suggestions for improving the code structure or handling data fetching effectively.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).